# How to generate correct string for converting it by Gson in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am saving json response in shared preferences then when needed I extract it and parsing. I need to cover this piece with unit test. The problem is that when I retrieve the string from prefs its is in some weird format. So I need the correct format of the string so Gson can parse it when I call mock method.
Here is my string

```
        val user = "{"name":"User","type":"Free","lastName":"LastName","number":"12345","userName":"TestPerson"}"

fun SharedPreferences.getInfo(): User? =
    get(SharedPreferencesKeys.USER, null)?.let {
        //here is the error 
        //I need to pass here correct string
        Gson().fromJson(it, User::class.java)
    }
```

And this is the test method
[image]

So I need that val user make the correct format so the return statement start working

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add `\` character and reformat string like

```
val user = "{\"name\":\"User\"}"
```

Comment: All you had to do was use a [raw string](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-literals) delimited by triple quote: `"""{"name": "User"}"""`.